# how to get Emacs buffer-stack to ignore certain types of files?

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, I use a thing called `buffer-stack` to see and browse my open buffers, useful if I don't know what buffer I want to go to, but I just want to visually see the open buffers (the actual content, not the filenames). I have one keybinding for `buffer-stack-up` and another for `buffer-stack-down`, which allows me to scroll left and right between them.

I'd like to exclude certain types of buffers from this behavior. I can already exclude specific buffers by specifying the complete buffer name in a variable called `buffer-stack-untracked`, e.g. I can mark `*Messages*` as untracked.

How can I specify certain buffers as untracked using a REGEXP instead? For example, I'd like to exclude buffers that contain the REGEXP `Help` or `.html`, even though I can't predict the entire filename.

How do I do this? If it's not possible to do this using `buffer-stack`, then what package will give me the behavior I want?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will be a good starting point.

```
(defun buffer-stack-filter-regexp (buffer)
  "Non-nil if buffer is in buffer-stack-tracked."
  (not (or (string-match "Help\\|html" (buffer-name buffer))
           (member buffer buffer-stack-untracked))))
(setq buffer-stack-filter 'buffer-stack-filter-regexp)
```

Comment: In fact that had the opposite effect. I found myself flipping through buffers like `edit server`, `Minibuf-0`, `Echo-area-1`, `Echo-area-2`, and `code-conversion-work`.

Comment: Edited the answer to better match the original behavior

Comment: I get `end of file during parsing`.

Comment: Missed a closing paren.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks. When I execute `buffer-stack-up` or `buffer-stack-down`, I get `Symbol's value as variable is void: name`

Comment: i'm stinking it up here.  one last fix.  change name to buffer.  edited it to reflect that.  its subtle.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I added some regexp to make it stop tracking `Minibuf` and `echo-area`. So it's like this: `(defun buffer-stack-filter-regexp (buffer)
  "Non-nil if buffer is in buffer-stack-tracked."
  (not (or (string-match "Help\\|html\\|minibuf\\|echo\\|conversion\\|server\\|Messages" (buffer-name buffer))
           (member buffer buffer-stack-untracked))))
(setq buffer-stack-filter 'buffer-stack-filter-regexp)`